# Trying to find average start time within a range of start times with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data on employee punch-ins and punch-outs. I'm trying to write a SQL query that returns average start time and stop time.

For example, if employee A records the following punch-in data:

[image]

what are some ways to find average start and stop time?

So far I've tried:

```
"SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`start_time`))) FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN 'dateRange1' AND 'dateRange2';"
```

**Solution** (thanks @Subin C Poonamgode for your help!):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`start_time`))) 
    FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN 'dateRange1' AND 'dateRange2' AND `start_time` <> '00:00:00';
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Did you mean by daterange 1 &  2 that you want to get result with two date range? or one date range?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure if it's correct (comparing against raw calculator)

Comment: @KDGamage one date range (Punch-Ins from Monday - Friday)

Comment: @KDGamage Monday (dateRange1) - Friday (dateRange2)

Comment: There are no stop times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query prints avg. check in time for Employee A(employee_id = 1).

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`start_time`))) 
    FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN 'dateRange1' AND 'dateRange2' AND
    `table`.employee_id =1  AND `start_time` <> '00:00:00'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response; I'm looking for average Punch-In time. For example if an employee punches in at 9am, 10am, 11am, 12pm, and 1pm, I would think the formula would return 11am...

Comment: what is the problem with query mentioned in `Question`

Comment: I'm getting closer I think... it may be because on days when employees aren't on the clock, database logs a '0' value, which may be why the average being outputted is slightly different than expected...

Comment: I updated 0 to '00:00:00' to respect the time format I'm working with... thanks for your help!